# How do I access my user account if another user forgot to sign out?

Tags: user-management

I'm having a problem with Ubuntu Studio 20.10 on a shared computer where if one user puts the computer to sleep without signing out the next user is not given the option of signing in without first logging into the first users account. It's there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

In the screen where you type the password (for the other user) there is, in the bottom right corner, a little icon which looks like a couple of people.

If you click on that icon, then you will be given the opportunity to login as another user (yourself).  The login screen under stock gnome is below

[image]

Here is the default lock screen for KDE-Plasma - note the 'switch user' icon below the text box for passwords

[image]

Comment: There is no such icon on my screen. Every other version of Linux that I've used has had an option like you describe (including past versions of ubuntu studio.)

Comment: @Jesse - what are you using for desktop?  Can you take a shot of the login screen?

Comment: I'm using KDE here's a picture of the login screen. https://imgur.com/6uNxZTD

Comment: @Jesse I've added a picture of the default KDE-Plasma login screen, with a prominent 'switch user' button.  I think that either you've got something else loaded.

Comment: here's the information from the info center on my computer: Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 20.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.8.0-36-lowlatency
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 3.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa DRI Intel® HD Graphics 4000 

I've installed this on 2 different computers with the same result. I did a basic install and didn't really change anything

Comment: I installed UbuntuStudio and have run into the problem that you mention.  Upon reflection this may be by design, as Studio may be used to run tasks which should not be interrupted, and login in another user might cause problems for audio/video applications.

Comment: I've wondered about that too. In my situation my partner now knows my password and generally just uses my account because of the hassles of not being able to sign out witch is far more likely to interrupt what I have going on. It's also true of the type of creative work that studio is geared toward that many people work in teams and sometimes have shared equipment. Whether this is a bug or by design I think it's important that people at least have an option that can be enabled easily for someone to be able to log into their account without having to login to the last used account first.

Comment: @Jesse I understand what you mean - my son'scomputer blew up and he used mine for a while.  It seemed he was always logged in when he left the house....  You could always open a console window and reboot from there, but that does mean possibly losing some work.